# PHP APCu: Does apc_fetch() pass references?

Tags: php, performance, caching

Or does it create a copy of whatever is stored and add this to the script's local memory?

I have a case in which I'm deciding whether to use APCu to cache a seldom changed variable (once a month), or just to re-declare that variable at run time (optimised with OpCache), and upload a new PHP script whenever I change it.

Comment: How do you see it to be able to pass a reference when it runs in another memory block?

Comment: Hmmm sorry, Iam not too familiar with the memory structure behind PHP, but seeing how a fixed amount of memory is allocated per script execution, what you say makes sense... I've found an experiment to confirm this which I will be posting as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @zerkmes mentions in his comment, apc_fetch passing references should not be the expected behavior, due to each script having a fixed block of allocated memory.

I've found an experiment (posted by **aktharmiah at gmail dot com**) in the comments section of: http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-fetch.php which confirms this:

```
class foo{
    public $bar;    
}

apc_add("foo",  new foo());

$fooGot    =    apc_fetch("foo");
$fooGot->bar = 1234;    

print_r(apc_fetch("foo"));
echo '<br>';
print_r($fooGot);
```

Indeed prints:

foo Object ( [bar] => )

foo Object ( [bar] => 1234 )